# Convert integer to string in lua?

Tags: string, types, lua, integer, ti-nspire

I've seen lot's of answers to convert strings to integers, but how can I convert integers to strings? When I try `microseconds.toString()` I get the following error: `attempt to index upvalue 'microseconds' (a number value)`

Please note that this is on a ti-nspire running os 4.5.0.1180

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: try tostring(microseconds)

Comment: ... or `string.format("%d", microseconds)` but in concatentation `"foo" .. microseconds` the number should coerce into a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-tostring

> **tostring (e)**

> Receives an argument of any type and converts it to a
> string in a reasonable format. For complete control of how numbers are
> converted, use `string.format`. If the metatable of e has a "`__tostring`"
> field, then tostring calls the corresponding value with e as argument,
> and uses the result of the call as its result.

`tostring` is mentioned in Chapter 1, **page 1** of the [NSpire Lua Scripting API Reference Guide](https://education.ti.com/download/en/ed-tech/59108CCE54484B76AF68879C217D47B2/7EFB09CED41C4190AFF8F60283B6727A/TI-Nspire%20Lua%20Scripting%20API%20Reference%20Guide.pdf)...